# Graphviz use of dot with accent

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz

I have some functions to work with graphviz and networkx.
If my graph doesn't contains any accent character, everything works fine.

But if I have this file test.txt :

```
strict graph {
   "Français"
}
```

And I run this command:
`dot.exe -Tdot test.txt -o result.txt`

And end up with this file:

```
strict graph {
    graph [bb="0,0,83.193,36"];
    node [label="\N"];
    Français     [height=0.5,
        pos="41.596,18",
        width=1.1555];
}
```

I don't have the double quotes around the node name
Then, in Python, I'm trying to load this file with this command:

`graph = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot("result.txt")`

And now, if I want to see my node, I do:

`graph.nodes`

And I get this result:

`NodeView(('Fran', 'ç', 'ais'))`
I have 3 nodes instead of one.

If I add the double quote in result.txt, I got only one node.

What can I do in order to keep the double quotes in result.txt?

EDIT:
Thanks to [sroush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12317235/sroush), I know that I can add a space at the end of each node and the double quotes will stay in the result. But this solution will make the position of each nodes a little wrong.
But why the double quotes doesn't stay before ?

Can we force it ? Because I can't edit my result.txt file, all the process is done automatically. And the result can contains hundreds of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you might add quotes around the node name in the `result.txt` file

```
strict graph {
    graph [bb="0,0,83.193,36"];
    node [label="\N"];
    "Français"     [height=0.5,
        pos="41.596,18",
        width=1.1555];
}
```

---

```
>>> graph = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot("result.txt")
>>> graph.nodes()
NodeView(('Français',))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do it automatically.
I will edit my post to put more information.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a space works (though it will alter the appearance):

```
strict graph {
   "Français "
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it might be a solution if I don't find something else.